# Not able to connect to Cloud SQL (MySQL) from GKE using a Spring-Boot application

Tags: java, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a Spring Boot MySQL extractor, which uses jdbctemplate for making connection to Cloud SQL MySQL instance. The credentials are present in **application.properties** file.

I am using the following connection URL : `jdbc:mysql://[Public-IP]:3306/[database_name]`

When I run this application I am facing the following error :

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:154)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:145)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:493)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:585)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
        ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: does your mysql "allow remote connections" ("by default" it shouldn't)? could you test the access/credentials elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add the Cloud SQL Proxy docker image to your pod using the "sidecar" container pattern. You can find the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#proxy

Comment: Hi Claudio, I am not trying to connect using Cloud SQL Proxy docker, rather I am connecting using a private IP address. Here is the doc : https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#private-ip

Comment: Hello Aman, in your connection string you wrote [Public-IP] not Private. In any case I really suggest you to use Cloud SQL Proxy, is really super easy to use and is really more secure because you connect via service account.If you need an help ask me.

Comment: Sorry I meant public, but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: No problem. You are wellcome.

Comment: here is a simple way of using sql proxy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKoaiH_xYB8&t=21s